# AJAX: Enviar valor para arquivo php, fazer consulta usando esse valor e returnar um array Json

Tags: php, ajax

Alguém pode me ajudar com esse código? Por que não funciona? Estou tentando enviar um valor recebido por um formulário para um arquivo php, usar esse valor na minha query SQL buscando por registros que contenham esse valor, retornar um array Json com o(s) resultado(s) e imprimi-los na tela usando html.

Minha Query SELECT:

```php
$sql= "SELECT * FROM incidente WHERE (titulo LIKE '%':buscar'%' OR descricao LIKE '%':buscar'%')";

//...

$recebeConexao->bindParam(':buscar', $_POST['busca'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Código HTML:

```html
<!-- here I am creating a form whit text input and a button that call the function enviar() -->

<form id="buscar">
  <input id="busca" name="busca" type="text" placeholder="Buscar incidente" />
  <input onclick="enviar()"  type="button" value="ok" />
</form>

<!-- creating a array that will receive values from SQL consult -->

<div id="content" class="content">   
  <article class="underline">\
    <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"\ 
      src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>\
    <h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit">'+tit+'</a></h2>\
    <p id="desc">'+desc+'</p>\
    <div class="date" id="date">'+dateVal+'</div>\
    <img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">\
    <img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">\
  </article>'
</div>
```

Função enviar():

```js
function enviar() {
  function viewData(data, el) {
    var content = '';
    for (var i in data) {
      var tit = data[i].titulo;
      var desc = data[i].descricao;
      var dateVal = data[i].data;
      content += '<article class="underline">\
        <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"\ 
        src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>\
        <h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit">'+tit+'</a></h2>\
        <p id="desc">'+desc+'</p>\
        <div class="date" id="date">'+dateVal+'</div>\
        <img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">\
        <img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">\
       </article>';
    }
    $('#'+el).html(content);
  }
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
      var formula = $('#buscar').serialize();
      type: "POST",
      data:formula,
      url: "http:/ip/connect/www/buscar.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        viewData(data,'content');
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Estou recebendo o erro: `enviar is not defined`...

Comment: Em qual lugar da página você está declarando a função `enviar();`? Este erro é porque a pagina está tentando chamar uma função que não existe ou ainda não foi declarada.

Comment: `viewData()` está definida dentro de `enviar()`? qual é o problema o json não chega? sua consulta não retorna nada?

Comment: Você colocou a função viewData dentro da função enviar, e chamou a função ViewData sem chamar a função enviar. Assim é o mesmo que a dizer que a função viewData Não existisse. E dá erro.

Answer (score 1):

1) Confira se existe declaração da tag `<script>`, para seu código javascript. Assim como se sua consulta retorna valores e, principalmente, formate o retorno da query transformando-a em Json.

2) Quando você chama um evento **onclick**: `onclick="enviar()"`, é esperado que esse método retorne algo para ti (`true/false`).

Neste caso, recomendo algumas modificações:

HTML:

```
<form id="buscar">
  <input id="busca" name="busca" type="text" placeholder="Buscar incidente" />
  <input id="btnBuscar" type="button" value="ok" /> <!-- Retirada do evento onclick e adição de id ao botão. -->
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function viewData(data, el) {
    var content = '';
    for (var i in data) {
      var tit = data[i].titulo;
      var desc = data[i].descricao;
      var dateVal = data[i].data;
      content += '<article class="underline">\
        <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"\ 
        src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>\
        <h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit">'+tit+'</a></h2>\
        <p id="desc">'+desc+'</p>\
        <div class="date" id="date">'+dateVal+'</div>\
        <img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">\
        <img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">\
       </article>';
    }
    $('#'+el).html(content);
  }
$("#btnBuscar").click(function() { //Retirada de função sem retorno "Enviar" e adição de evento para capturar o click do botão com id "btnBuscar"
    $.ajax({
      var formula = $('#buscar').serialize();
      type: "POST",
      data:formula,
      url: "http:/ip/connect/www/buscar.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
        viewData(data,'content');
      }
    });
  });
```

Creio que resolva...caso contrário, volte a postar com mais detalhes a respeito do erro.

Comment: Resolvido na verdade o serialize(var formula = $('#buscar').serialize();) estava dentro do ajax e teria que ficar antes...Obrigada!!

Answer (score 1):

Experimente fazer assim:

```
var enviar = function() {
  viewData : function(data, el) {
    var content = '';
    for (var i in data) {
      var tit = data[i].titulo;
      var desc = data[i].descricao;
      var dateVal = data[i].data;
      content += '<article class="underline">\
        <a href="incidente.html"><img id="incidente"\ 
        src="img/buraco.jpg" alt="Incidente" /></a>\
        <h2><a href="basic_markup.html" id="tit">'+tit+'</a></h2>\
        <p id="desc">'+desc+'</p>\
        <div class="date" id="date">'+dateVal+'</div>\
        <img class="tick" alt="não resolvido" src="img/no-tick.png">\
        <img class="apoio" alt="apoiar" src="img/apoio.png">\
       </article>';
    }
    $('#'+el).html(content);
  }
}
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
      var formula = $('#buscar').serialize();
      type: "POST",
      data:formula,
      url: "http:/ip/connect/www/buscar.php",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function (data) {
         enviar.viewData(data,'content');
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

1) Chamada da Funcao pesquisa

```
   $habilitado = 's';$pesquisa_T = "paulo tarciso";
   $vai_T = pesquisa($pesquisa_T,$habilitado);
```

2) Funcao pesquisa

```
    function pesquisa($pesquisa_T, $habilitado){
        $pdo = conectar("conexao com Banco de Dados");
       $pesquisa = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM itens_coluna
            WHERE (dsc_noticia LIKE CONCAT('%',:Oque,'%') OR
                  titulo LIKE CONCAT('%',:Oque,'%')) AND
                  habilitado = :habilita");

  $pesquisa->bindParam(":Oque",$pesquisa_T, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $pesquisa->bindParam(":habilita",$habilitado, PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $pesquisa->execute();
  return $pesquisa->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }
```